# Libgdx pause() method not working

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So I am trying to run a snippet of code when the user closes the app by pressing the home button. I am guessing the `pause()` method is called at this moment. However, when I try to `println` something in the pause method and I "pause" the app by pressing the home button, the `pause()` function never seems to run. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Override
public void pause() {
    System.out.println("here");
}
```

Comment: Can you add some more context to your example?  The 3 line method is correct, but does not help answer your problem. Could it be that you should use a logger vs. stdout?

Comment: Your problem might be that in Android if you want to override the `Activity` pause method it's `onPause`, not `pause`.

Comment: Hey please read my response below. Also i cant use onPause :/ it gives me an error at override

Comment: Use `Gdx.app.log()` instead of `System.out.println();`

Comment: But my server call below also doesnt work :/ @Tenfour04

Comment: Does the log call not work?

Comment: @DavidM As he is talking about libgdx, `pause` should be right. It gets called, when androids `onPause` gets called.

Comment: @NexonIsdumb where is this `pause` method? If it is inside a class, which implements the `Screen` interface, make sure your `ApplicationListener` class calls `Screen#pause()` in it's `pause()` method. The `Game` class should do this by default.

Comment: @Tenfour04 the log call did not work :/

Comment: @Springrbua i am using Game class and pause is still not working. Wonder why.

Comment: Then you need to share more code. What class is this `pause` method in, and how is your game structured?

Comment: public class GameRoom extends Game {
 @Override
    public void pause() {
    }
}
there is my pause method. Shouldn't this be working? id post the whole class but its kinda long. :/

Comment: @Tenfour04 I just figured out that it calls the pause function in the main class... Do you know how i could make this call in the current GameRoom class rather than the main one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, it looks like you overrode the `pause` method in your Game class without calling the super method:

```
public void pause(){
    //nothing
}
```

Therefore, the Game class's original functionality of calling the `pause()` method of the active Screen class has been removed by you.

You should make sure to call the super method like this so you aren't removing functionality:

```
public void pause(){
    super.pause();
    //other code you might want to add
}
```

If you don't need to add code here, you shouldn't override `pause()` in the Game class at all.

The bottom line is, whenever you override a method, always call the super-class's implementation of that same method unless you specifically want to change its behavior rather than just add to it.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot! I got it fixed in some random way but this helped :)!